# Linearise the system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system $$\begin{pmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 4x-4xy \\ -9y+18xy \end{pmatrix}$$

Find the equilibria and for each equilibrium linearise the system near that equilibrium.

I know that in order to find the equilibria I must solve the simultaneous equations $$4x-4xy=0 \text{ and } -9y+18xy=0.$$

This gives me $x=0,y=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}, y=1.$

However, I'm not sure what I'm being asked to do in the next part. Could someone explain what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearising a system around a point means to remove the non-linear terms in a way that changes the values of the system as little as possible close to that point.

Take first the equilibrium point $(x, y) = (0,0)$. Close to that point (let's say $-10^{-3}<x, y < 10^{-3}$), the term $xy$ is very small compared both to $x$ and to $y$, so the system behaves a lot like
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4x \\ -9y \end{pmatrix}
$$
As for the other equilibrium point, $(x, y) = (1/2, 1)$, note that 
$$
2xy = (2x-1)(y-1) +2x+y-1
$$
We may use this to rewrite the system into
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 8x+2 y -2 -2(2x-1)(y-1)\\ 18x - 9+9(2x-1)(y-1) \end{pmatrix}
$$
Again, the nonlinear term $(2x-1)(y-1)$ will be negligible close to the equilibrium point, and we can therefore disregard it to obtain
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot x \\ \dot y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 8x+2 y -2 \\ 18x - 9 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: At the second point it is probably easier to actually get the Jacobian by differentiation...